# Passing a C++ pointer between C and Python

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api

I have a python extension module written in C++, which contains multiple functions. One of these generates an instance of a custom structure, which I then want to use with other functions of my module in Python as follows

```
import MyModule
var = MyModule.genFunc()
MyModule.readFunc(var)
```

To do this, I've tried using PyCapsule objects to pass a pointer to these objects between Python and C, but this produces errors when attempting to read them in the second C function ("PyCapsule_GetPointer called with invalid PyCapsule object"). Python, however, if asked to print the PyCapsule object (var) correctly identifies it as a "'capsule object "testcapsule"'. My C code appears as follows:

```
struct MyStruct {
    int value;
};

static PyObject* genFunc(PyObject* self, PyObject *args) {
    MyStruct var;
    PyObject *capsuleTest;

    var.value = 1;
    capsuleTest = PyCapsule_New(&var, "testcapsule", NULL);
    return capsuleTest;
}

static PyObject* readFunc(PyObject* self, PyObject *args) {
    PyCapsule_GetPointer(args, "testcapsule");
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your capsule points to a local variable that only exists for the duration of `genFunc`. I'm surprised you get an error message rather than a crash though. You need to allocate `var` with `malloc` or make it a global variable or something similar to ensure that it lives as long as the capsule.

Comment: Apologies -- this was just written as demonstration code; the real example has some malloc calls, which is probably why it produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like stated in a comment to your question, you'll run into an issue when reading data from the local variable `MyStruct var`. For this you can use the third destructor to `PyCapsule_New`.

But that's not the reason for your problem just now. You're using `PyCapsule_GetPointer(args, "testcapsule")` on the `args` parameter. And since it's not a capsule, even though `var` is one, you might have defined the signature of the function as `METH_VARARGS`. Instead you need to unpack the tuple or use `METH_O`.

Comment: Apologies for late response -- but this was exactly the issue. Changing the function signature to METH_O fixed the pycapsule errors. Many thanks.